# Java chat application only picking up some sent messages

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, socketserver

I'm writing an all-in-one java chat program which will either act as a client or a server. I'm currently having this problem where, after the connection is established, the program only successfully recieves (or sends?) some of the messages. I've used a loop to spam through a load of junk and I've seen that the other end will only pick up some of the messages. I've never got a message to send manually.
Here is the code:

```
public class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {

private Connection c = Connection.getInstance();
private ChatInterface chatInterface;
private static ConnectionThread serverThread;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream dataIn;
private ObjectOutputStream dataOut;

public ConnectionThread() {}

public static synchronized ConnectionThread getInstance() {
    if (serverThread == null) {
        serverThread = new ConnectionThread();
    }
    return serverThread;
}

public void run() {
    // If the programs role is server, set up the server
    if (c.getRole() == ConnectionRole.SERVER) {
        try {
            setupServer();
            waitForConnection();
            setupStreams();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        do {
            try {
                chatInterface.addToChatHistory(dataIn.readUTF());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (c.getRole() == ConnectionRole.SERVER);
    }
    // If the programs role is client, set up a connection to the server
    if (c.getRole() == ConnectionRole.CLIENT) {
        try {
            setupClient();
            setupStreams();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        do {
            try {
                chatInterface.addToChatHistory(dataIn.readUTF());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (c.getRole() == ConnectionRole.CLIENT);
    }
}

private void setupClient() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("ATTEMPTING TO CONNECT...");
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    System.out.println("CONNECTED!");
}

private void setupServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("SETTING UP SERVER..");
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080, 1);
    System.out.println("SERVER SETUP");
}

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("WAITING FOR A CONNECTION...");
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("CONNECTION RECIEVED");
}

private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("SETTING UP STREAMS...");
    dataOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    dataIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    chatInterface = ChatInterface.getInstance();
    System.out.println("STREAMS SETUP");
}

public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("SENDING MESSAGE...");
    dataOut.writeUTF(message);
    chatInterface.addToChatHistory(message);
    System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT!");
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me why not all messages are being sent/picked up properly? I've been playing with it for quite a while now and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Where do you send messages....

Comment: This code will receive everything you send. If something isn't received, you didn't send it. You should stop reading when `readUTF()` throws `EOFException`, and you don't need `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` for this: `DataInput/OutputStreams` are sufficient.

Comment: Messages are sent using the sendMessage method at the bottom. This method is called by another class when the user clicks the send button in the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after following EJP's recommendation to switch to `DataInput/OutputStreams` which worked straight away. Although I did need to be using `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` so I switched back. I found that I got the same issue again, until I switched to `write/readObject` instead of `write/readUTF`. If I cast the `readObject` to `(String)` it would then manage to receive every message. 
So if anyone is having the same problem with `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` using `write/readUTF` try using `write/readObject` instead.